# Why is Azure Scale-Out Crashing the Web App

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service, umbraco

I'm currently running Umbraco on a web app for Microsoft Azure. Anytime I enable scaling out and the web app starts scaling out, I get the error:
"Process cannot access the file, Examine Indexes write.lock because it is being used by another file.

The website then needs to be restarted before it becomes fully functioning again. Is there a setting on Umbraco that I'm missing?
Or is it something that happens with Azure Web Apps Auto Scaling features?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with the indexes. Your index appears to be getting locked when scaling out. Ideally if you're running on a load balanced environment, you should have a single index for all environments instead of on a per instance basis. I've used Azure Search in the past and it's worked perfectly, swapping out the index isn't too difficult with Umbraco, plenty of information available online. Good example [here](https://github.com/darrenferguson/UmbracoAzureSearch)

In the future you shouldn't need to restart the entire site, rebuilding the indexes should be fine.

Also, what version of Umbraco are you running? This may be of some help, I encountered some similar issues a few months ago - unrelated to scaling though.
https://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-10735

Comment: I'm running umbraco 7.3, azure search replaces the Examine Indexes I assume?

Comment: @EricShay Yeah, that's a correct! If you're looking to build a truly scalable envrionment you should look into storing the media library on Azure blob storage as well - again, plenty of info online. Please mark the answer as resolved if I've helped out, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to isolate your index files so they aren’t shared across the difference instances and don’t lock each other out.  There’s a few ways to do this based on the version you are running, but in 7.3, i think you update the index file location to include the instance name like ~/App_Data/TEMP/ExamineIndexes/{machinename}/Internal/

For more details, see https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/getting-started/setup/server-setup/load-balancing/flexible#if-you-plan-on-using-auto-scaling